# SQL Server: Dynamic columns, insert into SQL table

Tags: sql-server, concatenation, dynamic-programming

I have a table named SQL_Standard:

```
ID name          sql_name      sourceTable
1  member_id     mem_id        tableA
2  member_dob    mem_dob       tableA
3  member_email  mem_email     tableA
4  member_phone                tableA
5  member_id     mbr_id        tableB
6  member_dob    mbr_dob       tableB
7  member_email                tableB
8  member_phone                tableB
9  member_id     sub_id        tableC
10 member_id     emp_id        tableC
11 member_dob    sub_dob       tableC
12 member_email                tableC
13 member_phone sub_phn        tableC
```

I also have tableA, tableB, tableC. Sql_name blank means that the column does not exists in that table. But we have standard name as member_id,member_dob, , member_email, member_phone because these are standard columns for all source tables.

```
tableA
mem_id    mem_dob      mem_email
1011      1986-05-05  bsi@yahoo.com
1012      1987-09-09  bw@gmail.com

tableB
mbr_id   mbr_dob
5555     1965-02-09

tableC
sub_id  emp_id  sub_dob      sub_phn 
15       56     19474-02-05  808-888-8888
```

We ultimately want to load all the records from all source tables to the combined table. The columns which do not exists in sourcetable will not get loaded.

I want to achieve two goals here:

1. Load all records from source table to combined table
2. Where there are two names for source table (ID 9 and 10), concatenate 
   two columns into one.

Combined table:

```
Member_id   member_dob  member_email member_phone  sourcetable

1011       1986-05-05   bsi@yahoo.com              tableA
1012       1987-09-09   bw@gmail.com               tableA
5555       1965-02-09                              tableB
1556       19474-02-05  808-888-8888               tableC
```

**My efforts:**

```
DECLARE @memID VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @DOB   VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @email VARCHAR( 20)
DECLARE @phone VARCHAR(20)

SET @source_table = (SELECT top 1 sourcetable from SQL_Standard )


SELECT @memID = sql_name 
from SQL_Standard 
where (name = 'member_id' and sourcetable = @source_table) 

SELECT @DOB = sql_name 
from SQL_Standard 
where (name = 'member_dob' and sourcetable = @source_table) 

SELECT @email = sql_name 
from SQL_Standard 
where (name = 'member_email' and sourcetable = @source_table) 

SELECT @phone = sql_name 
from SQL_Standard 
where (name = 'member_phone' and sourcetable = @source_table)    

SELECT @sqlStr = ' ; 
WITH Tableinfo1 AS (SELECT [' + @memID +  '] 
,[' + @DOB +  ']
,[' + @email +  ']
,[' + @phone +  ']
FROM [' + @source_table + '] ) 

SELECT * FROM Tableinfo1'

EXEC (@sqlstr)
```

Comment: What are you asking? IS there any error when you do what you did?

Comment: Why aren't you doing a join on the 3 tables?  what part of this is genuinely dynamic?

Comment: Yes, First of all, my script only works if there are all 4 columns in sourcetables. So it does not take care of the missing column.
Secondly, it does not handles concatenation.
Thanks

Comment: How are you generating `SQL_Standard`?

Comment: It is generated by a SAS program. I am working from SQL_Standard table.

Comment: do the names and columns ever change?

Comment: name in SQL_Standard would never change but sql_name is the column name in the source table, so they change.

Comment: Error message when a column does not exist: An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.

Comment: Its not working. I need a robust solution that would only pick up the columns from the source table which exists.

Comment: what is not working, what part of that would not work? Where are you adding the If statements?

Comment: Can you please write if statements for me?

Answer (score 0):

```
IF @memID is not null or @DOB is not null or @email  is not null or @phone is not null  -- make sure at least 1 is there
BEGIN
    SET @sqlStr = ' ; WITH Tableinfo1 AS (SELECT '

    if  @memID is not null
      SET  @sqlStr= @sqlStr + ' [' + @memID +  '],' 
    if  @DOB is not null
      SET  @sqlStr= @sqlStr + ' [' + @DOB +  '],' 
    if   @email  is not null
      SET  @sqlStr= @sqlStr + ' [' +  @email +  '],' 
    if  @phone is not null
      SET  @sqlStr= @sqlStr + ' [' + @phone +  '],' 

    SET @sqlStr =@sqlStr + ' FROM [' + @source_table + '] )'

    --sheer laziness below to remove last comma
    SET @sqlStr =REPLACE(@sqlStr, ', FROM',' FROM')
END
```

Add clauses as needed based on however many columns you need.  This is not ideal, but there is definitely code that you are running that you didn't post.

Incidentally,  how are you getting anything other than TableA here

```
SET @source_table = (SELECT top 1 sourcetable from SQL_Standard )
```

Comment: Okay, I know what you did there. But the motto was to insert data from tableA, tableB, tableC into a combined table. Your query will just bypass the records where eiter mem_id, dob , phone or email are null or ''. This is NOT what we want to do. We want to insert or select(as we are writing select only) into one table and leaving blank for the columns that do not exists.

Comment: why are you parameterizing instead of doing sub selects inner join other sub selects?

Comment: where is the actual data, these are just column names correct?  You need to have a similar `IF` set of statements for each source table, then treat the results as a regular join.